# Is it possible to use ngx-file-drop in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I need to use drag and drop option to upload a document in angular 5 project. When I use ngx-file-drop directive, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-file-drop/ngx-file-drop/ngx-file-drop.component.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-file-drop/ngx-file-drop/ngx-file-drop.component.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Comment: Looks like it should work - please share the code so we can review.

Answer (score 1):

As stated here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop, it is

> An Angular 9 module for simple desktop file and folder drag and drop

and also

> For previous Angular support please use older versions.

What version are you currently using?
As I have never used this package before and cannot be sure about it, I would suggest trying another version (v3.0.2 seems to be the one for Angular 5). In order to do that, just install the package version like that `npm i ngx-file-drop@3.0.2`.